# Php pdf image preview code

Tags: php, pdf

I try to generate php code in order to preview an image from a pdf file. Here is my code. There is an error but i cannot understand where it is. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
 <?php 
//Get Menu Bar
include('navigate.php'); 
?>

<table cellspacing="4" width=100%><tr><?php if(!$vol){ ?><td bgcolor="eeeeee" width="50%" valign="top">
<h3 style=" text-shadow:#003">Latest News:</h3>

<?php 
$latest=mysql_query("select * from articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", $link);
while ($article = mysql_fetch_array($latest)) {
$thevolume= $article['volume'];
$title=     $article['title'];
$author=    $article['author_main'];
$abstract=  $article['abstract'];
$pdf=       $article['pdf'];
$im =       new imagick('pdf');
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');

?>
<a href="<?php echo $pdf; ?> "PDF:  ?php echo "$title - $author"; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $im; ?> " WIDTH="98%" border="1" title="<?php echo "$title - $author"; ?>  " caption="Click here to open PDF"  /> 
</a>
```

Comment: "There is an error but i cannot understand where it is". Please learn to read and then learn to be polite. You are not forced to reply. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but as you see there are people that can be polite and available to help. There is no need for you to make such a post as someone has already helped me and there is an approved answer. I made a clear question, I was polite, some others are here just to make ironic comments and not help at all. So perhaps you are the one who has to familiarize himself with acting within this site, even if you think you're an advanced user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to pass as parameter a path to PDF file, not only the string 'pdf': http://php.net/imagick.construct

If $article['pdf'] contains it you must to use:

```
$im = new imagick(realpath($pdf) . '[0]');
```

$im still being a resource that contains a object instance of imagick, and not the image or pdf document itself, so you must to do this to inline image in HTML (if you want to use JPEG, I would use PNG):

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php
echo base64_encode($im->getImageBlob());
?> " WIDTH="98%" border="1" title="<?php
echo htmlspecialchars("$title - $author");
?>  " caption="Click here to open PDF"  />
```

Note the usage of htmlspecialchars ( http://php.net/htmlspecialchars ) to output strings to navigator and getImageBlob ( http://php.net/imagick.getimageblob ) to get image data (if available) and finally I will encode it in base64 to inline it in HTML document.

If you want to link to a cached version of image you must to save it in a temporary file or create another PHP script to generate the image from PDF file.

Best regards,

#### Edit 1: How to create a JPEG thumbnail, from PHP manual:

You should read this: http://php.net/imagick.setimageformat#89210

This example will help you:

```
// convert to JPEG
$im->setImageColorspace(255);
$im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$im->setCompressionQuality(60);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
```

Probably you will wish to reduce image size:

```
$im->resizeImage(290, 375, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
```

And remember to import the page number (beginning with 0, not 1) adding '[0]' to file name as edited.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I'm checking it right now :)

Comment: The only question i have is the path.. My news articles are stored in a database and i call them with $pdf=article['pdf']; So I guess i use that instead of a path, right?

Comment: But, what type of field is in your database "pdf"? What contains it? a path or raw data of PDF file? Please, do a var_export($article) to view its content.

Comment: its a varchar. it contains a path to a .pdf file

Comment: Great! So you can use that path directly or will you need to generate the correct path using a base path? If you get the correct path you've got it! the code will work with it (and remember, "jpeg" is the image format, not "jpg" and you must to add "[0]" to file path as proposed to get only first PDF page).

Comment: Each record has its own pdf so I need to generate the path, as I use the very last entered record (its the one appeared in my main page)

Comment: So, where are we now? What is now the problem? Was there any progress with the problem?

Comment: I have to generate the correct path. I guess i wont have any further problem, thank you for your time!